# Handle one path specially

Tags: nginx

This is our current nginx config. It forwards redquests to the root resource on to a TeamCity instance.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ci.mycompany.com;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8111;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

I would like to expose one folder as `/myfiles` - not sending it to Team City. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For low priority location prefixes always the longest match takes priority:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ci.mycompany.com;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8111;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
  location /myfiles {
    #do something here
  }
}
```